# 2003 Alero wont start, and ideas greatly appreciated

Tags: starting, cranks-wont-run

Starters good, connections and battery good, jumped the starter and it turns over almost starting but never totally catches.  when the key is turned, all power shorts out like a bad ground. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by *"never totally catches"*?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the interest. I mean that if I hotwire the starter control to the battery, it will turn over but never start. The key is in the on position. If the key is turned to the start position, all power goes out but the starter will still turn the engine being hotwired and only hotwired.

Comment: Got it. Well regarding *"all power shorts out"*, I think it is normal for cars to shut off power to the dashboard/gauges when the key is turned to the **start** position, in order to provide the starter with maximum power. Does your car have a manual transmission? Could you push-start it?

Comment: It is an automatic transmission and im not sure if it is possible to push start them like with a manual. I am starting to aim towards a fuel issue but also am concerned of a timing issue. What might be the best way to tell?